# Is it possible to have temporary root access on Termux or any other terminal without rooting your Android phone?

Tags: root-access, terminal

I would like to know whether it is possible to be able to have temporary root access to an Android phone using a Termux or any other terminal, in the same way that Ubuntu does, without rooting your phone.

Comment: For an app to have root access, you need to root phone. But adb daemon can be started as root on userdebug and engineering builds by disabling secure adb. This way you will be able to have root access through adb. You can also use adb shell from within your phone or through PC. For more details on rooting, see Android Rooting section here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-boot-process-android-vs-linux-t3785254 Ask if any further details needed. I can post that as answer. Inform bootloader unlockability, custom recovery availability & value of "ro.build.type" property.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu for PC is permanently rooted. It comes with root user as well as with the mechanism to allow a process to gain superuser privilege when requested so and authenticated by the user (that which you considered temporary root). Android devices, on the other hand, do not provide the mechanism to gain superuser access. That mechanism, often involves installing a `su` binary coupled with some daemons and hacks, provides the user a way to gain elevated privileges and manage that privilege on a per app basis.

Even if you root a device, it is not like every app or process gets to have superuser access on its own. It is the user, through a superuser manager app such  as SuperSU and Magisk, who manages whether to permit temporary or permanent access to superuser privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Rooting phones is usually done using root exploit scripts which day by day Google releases patches. Most of the rooting tools and scripts focus on getting permanent root, but temporary root is also achievable.

However, the question you have asked is to gain root access through an Android Application like Termux, which simulates a Terminal Emulator, which is not possible yet. But you can gain temporary root access nowadays if your device is at most Android 7.1.1 (Nougat) using Dirty Cow exploit, but you will need a PC. However, it will be temporary root access.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Shizuku](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.shizuku.privileged.api) app on the Play Store... follow the guide to set it up (only 3 steps) and you are good to go :-)

Comment: Hii,  Thanks for sharing this info. I found Shizuku highly useful. I was able to use it together with Termux as I required. Not only that, but I was also able to use it with aShell which enabled me to directly pass ADB commands without connecting my phone to a PC.